# Webapi 2.0 how to implement refresh JWT token when access token expired

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, webforms, asp.net-web-api2, dotnet-httpclient

I am quite new in web API implementation, I have created a web API service to use it with `ASP.net web form` applications as well as some stand alone applications(C# Console/Windows application) using `HttpClient` object.

I have implemented a basic JWT access token authentication with expiration time limit in web api, this authentication technique is working fine until token not expired, when token get expired web api does not accept request as token has expired! which is fine as per authentication implementation, but I want to implement refresh token logic in web api so token can renew/refersh and client should be able to use the web api resource.

I googled a lot but unable to find the proper implementation of refresh token logic. Please help me if any one has right approach to handle the expired access token.

Following are the steps that I have followed to use the web api in asp.net application.

1. In ASP.net web form login page I called the web API "TokenController" this controller take two arguments loginID and password and return the JWT token that I stored in session object.
2. Now whenever my client application need too use the web api resource has to send the access token in request header while making call to web api using `httpclient`.
3. But when token get expired client unable use the web api resource he has to login again and renew the token! this I don't want, user should not prompt to be login again as application session out time not elapsed yet.

How do I refresh the token without forcing user to login again.

If my given below JWT access token implementation logic is not suitable or it is incorrect, please let me know the correct way.

Following is the code.

**WebAPI**

AuthHandler.cs

```
  public class AuthHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {

    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,
                CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage errorResponse = null;           
        try
        {
            IEnumerable<string> authHeaderValues;
            request.Headers.TryGetValues("Authorization", out authHeaderValues);

            if (authHeaderValues == null)
                return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

            var requestToken = authHeaderValues.ElementAt(0);

            var token = "";

            if (requestToken.StartsWith("Bearer ", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                token = requestToken.Substring("Bearer ".Length);
            }

            var secret = "w$e$#*az";

            ClaimsPrincipal cp = ValidateToken(token, secret, true);


            Thread.CurrentPrincipal = cp;

            if (HttpContext.Current != null)
            {
                Thread.CurrentPrincipal = cp;
                HttpContext.Current.User = cp;
            }
        }
        catch (SignatureVerificationException ex)
        {
            errorResponse = request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, ex.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            errorResponse = request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex.Message);
        }


        return errorResponse != null
            ? Task.FromResult(errorResponse)
            : base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }

    private static ClaimsPrincipal ValidateToken(string token, string secret, bool checkExpiration)
    {
        var jsonSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        string payloadJson = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            payloadJson = JsonWebToken.Decode(token, secret);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw new SignatureVerificationException("Unauthorized access!");
        }

        var payloadData = jsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(payloadJson);


        object exp;
        if (payloadData != null && (checkExpiration && payloadData.TryGetValue("exp", out exp)))
        {
            var validTo = AuthFactory.FromUnixTime(long.Parse(exp.ToString()));
            if (DateTime.Compare(validTo, DateTime.UtcNow) <= 0)
            {
                throw new SignatureVerificationException("Token is expired!");
            }
        }

        var clmsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity("Federation", ClaimTypes.Name, ClaimTypes.Role);

        var claims = new List<Claim>();

        if (payloadData != null)
            foreach (var pair in payloadData)
            {
                var claimType = pair.Key;

                var source = pair.Value as ArrayList;

                if (source != null)
                {
                    claims.AddRange(from object item in source
                                    select new Claim(claimType, item.ToString(), ClaimValueTypes.String));

                    continue;
                }

                switch (pair.Key.ToUpper())
                {
                    case "USERNAME":
                        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, pair.Value.ToString(), ClaimValueTypes.String));
                        break;
                    case "EMAILID":
                        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, pair.Value.ToString(), ClaimValueTypes.Email));
                        break;
                    case "USERID":
                        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.UserData, pair.Value.ToString(), ClaimValueTypes.Integer));
                        break;
                    default:
                        claims.Add(new Claim(claimType, pair.Value.ToString(), ClaimValueTypes.String));
                        break;
                }
            }

        clmsIdentity.AddClaims(claims);

        ClaimsPrincipal cp = new ClaimsPrincipal(clmsIdentity);

        return cp;
    }


}
```

AuthFactory.cs

```
public static class AuthFactory
{
internal static DateTime FromUnixTime(double unixTime)
{
    var epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
    return epoch.AddSeconds(unixTime);
}


internal static string CreateToken(User user, string loginID, out double issuedAt, out double expiryAt)
{

    var unixEpoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
    expiryAt = Math.Round((DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(TokenLifeDuration) - unixEpoch).TotalSeconds);
    issuedAt = Math.Round((DateTime.UtcNow - unixEpoch).TotalSeconds);

    var payload = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            {enmUserIdentity.UserName.ToString(), user.Name},
            {enmUserIdentity.EmailID.ToString(), user.Email},
            {enmUserIdentity.UserID.ToString(), user.UserID},
            {enmUserIdentity.LoginID.ToString(), loginID}
            ,{"iat", issuedAt}
            ,{"exp", expiryAt}
        };

    var secret = "w$e$#*az";

    var token = JsonWebToken.Encode(payload, secret, JwtHashAlgorithm.HS256);

    return token;
}

public static int TokenLifeDuration
{
    get
    {
        int tokenLifeDuration = 20; // in minuets
        return tokenLifeDuration;
    }
}

internal static string CreateMasterToken(int userID, string loginID)
{

    var payload = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            {enmUserIdentity.LoginID.ToString(), loginID},
            {enmUserIdentity.UserID.ToString(), userID},
            {"instanceid", DateTime.Now.ToFileTime()}
        };

    var secret = "w$e$#*az";

    var token = JsonWebToken.Encode(payload, secret, JwtHashAlgorithm.HS256);

    return token;
}
```

}

WebApiConfig.cs

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{

    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
        config.EnableCors(cors);

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);

        config.MessageHandlers.Add(new AuthHandler());
    }
}
```

TokenController .cs

```
public class TokenController : ApiController
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("signin")]
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Login(Login model)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = null;
        DataTable dtblLogin = null;
        double issuedAt;
        double expiryAt;

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            dtblLogin = LoginManager.GetUserLoginDetails(model.LoginID, model.Password, true);

            if (dtblLogin == null || dtblLogin.Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
            }
            else
            {
                User loggedInUser = new User();
                loggedInUser.UserID = Convert.ToInt32(dtblLogin.Rows[0]["UserID"]);
                loggedInUser.Email = Convert.ToString(dtblLogin.Rows[0]["UserEmailID"]);
                loggedInUser.Name = Convert.ToString(dtblLogin.Rows[0]["LastName"]) + " " + Convert.ToString(dtblLogin.Rows[0]["FirstName"]);

                string token = AuthFactory.CreateToken(loggedInUser, model.LoginID, out issuedAt, out expiryAt);
                loggedInUser.Token = token;

                response = Request.CreateResponse(loggedInUser);

            }
        }
        else
        {
            response = Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);
        }
        return response;
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

}
```

PremiumCalculatorController.cs

```
PremiumCalculatorController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult CalculatAnnualPremium(PremiumFactorInfo premiumFactDetails)
    {
      PremiumInfo result;
      result = AnnualPremium.GetPremium(premiumFactDetails);
      return Ok(result);
    }
}
```

**Web Form Application**

Login.aspx.cs

```
public class Login
{
    protected void imgbtnLogin_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs s)
    {

    UserInfo loggedinUser = LoginManager.ValidateUser(txtUserID.text.trim(), txtPassword.text);

    if (loggedinUser != null)
    {

        byte[] password = LoginManager.EncryptPassword(txtPassword.text);

        APIToken tokenInfo = ApiLoginManager.Login(txtUserID.text.trim(), password);

        loggedinUser.AccessToken = tokenInfo.Token;

        Session.Add("LoggedInUser", loggedinUser);

        Response.Redirect("Home.aspx");

    }
    else
    {
        msg.Show("Logn ID or Password is invalid.");
    }


    }
}
```

ApiLoginManager.cs

```
public class ApiLoginManager
{
    public UserDetails Login(string userName, byte[] password)
    {
        APIToken result = null;
        UserLogin objLoginInfo;
        string webAPIBaseURL = "http://localhost/polwebapiService/"
        try
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                result = new UserDetails();
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(webAPIBaseURL);
                objLoginInfo = new UserLogin { LoginID = userName, Password = password };

                var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/token/Login", objLoginInfo);

                if (response.Result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    string jsonResponce = response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                    result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<APIToken>(jsonResponce);
                }

                response = null;
            }

            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

    }

}
```

AnnualPremiumCalculator.aspx.cs

```
public class AnnualPremiumCalculator
{
    protected void imgbtnCalculatePremium_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs s)
    { 
       string token = ((UserInfo)Session["LoggedInUser"]).AccessToken;
       PremiumFactors premiumFacts = CollectUserInputPremiumFactors();
       PremiumInfo premiumDet = CalculatePremium(premiumFacts, token);
       txtAnnulPremium.text = premiumDet.Premium;
       //other details so on 
    }

    public PremiumInfo CalculatePremium(PremiumFactors premiumFacts, string accessToken)
    {
        PremiumInfo result = null;
        string webAPIBaseURL = "http://localhost/polwebapiService/";
        try
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(webAPIBaseURL);

                StringContent content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(premiumFacts), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

                var response = client.PostAsync("api/calculators/PremiumCalculator", content);

                if (response.Result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    string jsonResponce = response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                    result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PremiumInfo>(jsonResponce);
                }

                response = null;

            }

            return result;
        }
        finally
        {

        }

    }

}
```

above is a sample code to illustrate the issue, it may have some typo.

Comment: whoever downgrading the question at least add comment why did you down voted it..

Comment: you should post minimum problem code when asking a question on SO,
PS: BTW I've not down-voted.

Comment: @AsifAli72090, I posted the code here to describe the my implementation, so people can understand what I have implemented, as this is my first web api implementation that I was not sure is correct approach I have used or not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have some remarks:

1. The access token is meant to be saved by the client and not in a session on the server. The same counts for the refresh token. The reason for that is, that there usually is no session. Smart clients can handle the token without session, MVC websites can use a cookie and the API doesn't know sessions. It is not forbidden, but then again you'll need to worry about session expiration and all users have to login again when you restart your server.
2. If you want to implement OAuth then read the [specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749). In there you will find everything you'll need to implement the refresh token.
3. In TokenController you handle the login. There you should check [other conditions](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3.2) as well.

- grant_type = password
- Content-Type has to be "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
- the request should only be handled if send over a secured line (https).

4. When the access_token is obtained and only if the refresh_token is requested, you should include the [refresh_token](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3.3) in the access_token.
5. You don't need a refresh token for [client applications](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.4.2) (grant_type = client_credentials) as those use a clientid / secret to obtain an access token. Extend TokenController to allow the client_credentials flow. Please note: refresh tokens are for *users* only and should be used only if they can be kept secret. A refresh token is very powerfull, so handle with care.
6. In order to [refresh an access token](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-6) you'll need to send the *refresh token* to the endpoint. In your case you can extend the TokenController to allow a refresh_token request. You'll need to check:

- grant_type = refresh_token
- Content-Type has to be "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

7. There are several scenarios for the refresh token, which you can also combine:

- Save the refresh token in a database. Each time a refresh token is used you can remove it from the database, then save the new refresh token which is also returned in the new access_token.
- Set the refresh token to a longer lifetime and do not refresh it when the access token is refreshed. In this case the returned access_token does not include a new refresh token. That way you'll need to login again after the refresh_token expires.

8. Please note, a refresh token that never expires and cannot be revoked gives a user unlimited access, so be carefull with your implementation.
9. In my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31747827/updating-roles-when-granting-refresh-token-in-web-api-2/44833586#44833586) you can see how a refresh token can be handled using Identity 2. You can consider to switch to Identity 2.

I think I've mentioned everything. Please let me know if I missed something or if something isn't clear.

Comment: This question was not about OAuth or Identity 2 ;). All what you said can be read from the tutorial I linked. Peace out.

Comment: Thanks @Ruard, I understand your pint that you have mentioned above, but I want to understand for few of your points like in your first point you have added "The access token is meant to be saved by the client and not in a session on the server", In my client application (asp.net web form) I am storing the token in session that will be used when client application will call the web API method by server side code using HttpClient class, Is this correct?

Comment: @Ruard do you have any sample code link where the complete life cycle of access_token -> Web API  Exposed Method -> refresh_token implantation are described.

Comment: @NeerajKumarGupta Like I said, it's not forbidden or bad, but it doesn't have to be your concern. Now you store a session cookie and link to information on the server. If you restart the server or the app is refreshed then all sessions may be gone. While without sessions you would store the information in the cookie and make the user responsable for the cookie.

Comment: @NeerajKumarGupta I do not have custom sample code. I use Identity, like the link in 9. Besides, the implementation of the refresh token depends on the chosen strategy, concerning lifetime and persistence. But the flow is easy. For webforms: Get access_token (includes refresh_token). access_token expires (or is about to expire), use refresh_token to get a new access_token. For client applications: do not use refresh_tokens but use the clientid/secret to get a (new) access token.

Comment: @NeerajKumarGupta All you have to do is extend your TokenController to implement the refresh token flow and (if you want client access) implement the client_credentials flow. The most important thing is that you need to send the refresh token to get a new access token.

Answer (score 6):

This can be done with a separate persisting refresh token. A nice tutorial at http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/handle-refresh-token-using-asp-net-core-2-0-and-json-web-token/

Comment: The question is tagged C#-4.0, webforms and asp.net-web-api2. How is this asp.net core 2.0 tutorial going to be of any help?

Comment: By giving a general idea of the solution without doing the whole work and thus learning for him. Its not about syntax, but design.

Comment: Thanks @Niko, I gone through your given link and understand the flow of request/response for the token. This is what I want to understand when my access token get expired, how API server issues the refresh token! that client application first check the response code/message for the request and then re request the access_token by sending the refresh_token as a master key to get the new access_token.

Comment: So my conclusion is when access_token get expired the actual request will process in 3 steps as follows. 1. Send the request to access the web API resource 2. Check the response of first request  response code /message is access token get expired? if yes then make a new call to API to get the new access token by sending refresh token . 3. use new access token and make a request to web API for actual resource (same as first request).  @Niko is  this my correct understanding?

Comment: I would say you now understand how refresh token works :) As images explain things easily, here is one [diagram](https://s3.amazonaws.com/dfc-wiki/en/images/9/96/OAuthRefreshFlow.png) from [salesforce.com](https://developer.salesforce.com/index.php%3Ftitle%3DDigging_Deeper_into_OAuth_2.0_on_Force.com%26oldid%3D50717)