# Xamarin.iOS / Web API JWT refresh token if it expires

Tags: c#, api, authentication, xamarin, jwt

I have a `Web API` that provides the user all the data that needs to be shown on my mobile application.

`OWIN JWT Authentication` is implemented and it's working properly. There's an endpoint `/oauth2/token` which provides the user a token and all the endpoints has `[Authorize]` attribute filter to validate it.

The token `expiration` is set to **5** minutes.

Login session is maintained through a separated `SESSION-ID` which is stored into the `Keychain` and also server-side to check the active session. Everytime a user login inside the application a new token is generated and the user can access API methods to get data.

#### The question

What if the user leave the application opened for more than 5 minutes (`Token expiration time`)? The token will not be available since it has expired, how can I refresh it? And when should I refresh it?

I read about refresh tokens but not sure how to handle them (Is thist the right choice?), since the `[Authorize]` attribute will just reject my call if the token has expired, without providing an expiration message, I can't understand when it is an expired token or an invalid one.

Answer (score 1):

> What if the user leave the application opened for more than 5 minutes
>   (Token expiration time)? The token will not be available since it has
>   expired, how can I refresh it?

If I understand right, you set `The token expiration to 5 minutes`,  that means if the user leave the application opened for more than 5 minutes, the token is no longer valid. Actually the user has to relogin to get the new token.

So back to your question, at the moment the token is expired, my advice is you can `present the loginPage and tell user that he has to login again to use the app`.

I don't know if there is another way to get a new token, if there is one, use may not have to relogin,.

Also, I found a thread that may help: [webapi-2-0-how-to-implement-refresh-jwt-token-when-access-token-expired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48320461/webapi-2-0-how-to-implement-refresh-jwt-token-when-access-token-expired)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't want users to login again actually, the session is already kept alive, i just need to know when and how can I refresh the token in order to avoid the situation where the user leave the application open without any actions. This would lead to the token expiration and the user will not be able to perform any calls.

Comment: If user call any api inside 5 mins, the token will refresh, right?

Comment: Exactly, this is the general idea to refresh the token. Don't know if it is correct or not but this is how it is implemented right now. The problem is if the user doesn't make any action within 5 minutes.

Comment: I think the idea should be use a Timer to count the time and call one api automatically and repeatedly every 5 mins even if user doesn't make any action within 5 minutes. It would be better if you can restart the Timer to re-count if any other api is called in your app.

Comment: Isn't a timer too much expensive for a mobile app? I don't know actually if it is good practice, I will look for it, thanks

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT did you find any solution? I'm having same issue